# Python 3.4, socket.error deprecated, new equivalent?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

Originally the code was written like this:

```
except socket.error, err:
    print('Socket connection error... Waiting 10 seconds to retry.')
    del self.sock
    time.sleep(10)
    try_count += 1
```

The intention is to catch a socket connection error, this used to be err, or something similar.

However I have seen on a previous answer that socket.error has been deprecated from 2.6 onwards.

I can also confirm that 3.4 flags an error that says it does not support this syntax.

Does anyone please know the 3.4 equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is with the syntax, not `socket.error`:

This python 2 code is deprecated:

```
except Exception, e:
```

In favor of

```
except Exception as e:
```

---

So you want:

```
except socket.error as err:
```

Comment: Thank you, `except Exception as e:` fixed that, however

flags up that 'e' value is not used anymore, same with err as that value, also flags up saying that Exception is too broad a clause. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, do you use the `e` value? If not, then omit the `as e`. I'm not suggesting you use `Exception`! Keep using `socket.error`

Comment: Works futher down in the code *shrug* I'll do as you suggest, thank you! :]

Comment: You never want the catch all exceptions by catching 'Exception', this is wrong! You end up catching exceptions you don't want (for example keyboard interrupt).

Comment: @danger89: 1) I'm not recommending catching `Exception`, reread my answer, 2) Doing so does not catch `KeyboardInterrupt` - that's not a subclass of `Exception`

Answer (score 6):

Indeed `socket.error` is deprecated in Python 3. You can now catch the superclass (OSError). And if want you can check within the except which kind of subclass of the exception was really raised (like ECONNREFUSED).

```
try:
    ...
except OSError as e:
    ...
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html